# C++ cast byte array from stringified bytes

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a very large string looking like the following:

std::string tmpString = "0xC7,0x04,0x33,0xC0,0x49,0x74,0x0A,..."

I'd like to cast each of the stringified bytes back to one byte array.
Whats the best solution for this case?

I'm using VC++

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
std::string tmpString = "0xC7,0x04,0x33,0xC0,0x49,0x74,0x0A,...";
...
std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
bytes.reserve((tmpString.length() / 5) + 1);
std::istringstream iss(tmpString);
std::string s;
while (std::getline(iss, s, ',')) {
    WORD num; // istreamstream does not have an '>>' operator for bytes
    std::istringstream(s) >> std::hex >> num;
    bytes.push_back(BYTE(num));
}
```

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: I see you opted for a mixed C/C++ solution instead of a pure C++ solution.

Comment: Since you provided an improvement for my solution, I considered changing it.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: fair enough

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str = ("0xC7,0x04,0x33,0xC0,0x49,0x74,0x0A");
char *p2str = str.c_str();
std::vector<BYTE> numVect;
char *p2c;
do
   int num = strtol(p2str,&p2c,16);
   p2str = p2c + 1; // skiping the ,
   numVect.push_back(BYTE(num));
while(*p2c);
```

Comment: This does not solve the requirement that a **byte** array be created. You are creating an **integer** array instead.